# Integrity constraint violation in Percona XtraDB Cluster

Tags: mysql, percona-server, galera

We have a PHP application that uses AWS Load Balancer that connects to 3 Percona Servers.

Before we used a single standard Percona Server and that never happened.

The cluster starts throwing Primary Key errors as shown below.

```
2014/10/14 18:50:20 [error] 23862#0: *193487 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '839027' for key 'PRIMARY'' in ../LeadNotes.php:423
2014/10/14 18:50:37 [error] 23864#0: *193116 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '226829' for key 'PRIMARY'' in ../Leads.php:588
2014/10/14 18:57:46 [error] 23865#0: *197705 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '438532' for key 'PRIMARY'' in ../EmailQueue.php:122
2014/10/14 19:01:19 [error] 23862#0: *199328 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1414' for key 'PRIMARY'' in ../EnrollModel.php:325
2014/10/14 19:11:31 [error] 23864#0: *203042 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '58078' for key 'PRIMARY'' in ../HelpTicketComments.php:94
```

All columns are auto-increment.
We have multiple non-persisitent connections coming from the web server trough the load balancer.
There are several cron tasks that connects to the load balancer all the time also.

I'm not sure what can cause this. I did a little bit of research and "wsrep_auto_increment_control" is set to ON.

This is my configuration file:

```
[mysqld]

user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/data/mysql
tmpdir      = /mnt/tmp

lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

default_time_zone = America/New_York

# -- Cluster Settings -------------------------- #

# Path to Galera library
wsrep_provider = /usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so

# Cluster connection URL contains the IPs of node#1, node#2 and node#3
# It should be empty during bootstrap
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://10.0.200.7,10.0.200.8,10.0.210.7
#wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://

# In order for Galera to work correctly binlog format should be ROW
binlog_format = ROW

# MyISAM storage engine has only experimental support
default_storage_engine = InnoDB

# This changes how InnoDB autoincrement locks are managed and is a requirement for Galera
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2

# Node #1 address
wsrep_node_address = 10.0.200.7

# SST method
wsrep_sst_method = xtrabackup-v2

# Authentication for SST method
wsrep_sst_auth="db1:xxxxxxx"

wsrep_slave_threads = 2

# Cluster and node name
wsrep_cluster_name = db1
wsrep_node_name = db1a

# ---------------------------------------------- #

key_buffer_size      = 256M
sort_buffer_size     = 3M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 3M
join_buffer_size     = 3M

max_allowed_packet   = 64M
thread_stack         = 512K
thread_cache_size    = 12

table_open_cache     = 2048
max_heap_table_size  = 128M
tmp_table_size       = 256M

myisam-recover       = BACKUP
max_connections      = 200
thread_concurrency   = 8

#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
# Cache size needs to be set to 0 before start with XtrabDB cluster
# It can ben changed during runtime
# http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.6/limitation.html

query_cache_type  = 1
query_cache_limit = 4M
query_cache_size  = 0

#
# * Logging and Replication
#

# It has to be logged to FILE to work with XtraDB Cluster
# http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.6/limitation.html
log_output = FILE

#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
long_query_time  = 10
#log-queries-not-using-indexes

#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.

server-id           = 1
log_bin             = /var/data/log/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size     = 512M
log-slave-updates

innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 24G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 8
innodb_log_file_size            = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 64M
innodb_thread_concurrency       = 0
innodb_file_format              = Barracuda
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT

innodb_read_io_threads          = 32
innodb_write_io_threads         = 16

# There is no point in having trx_commit to 1 in Galera Cluster
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0

innodb_file_per_table

#
# * Security
#

ssl-ca    = /etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt
ssl-cert  = /etc/mysql/keys/db1a.crt
ssl-key   = /etc/mysql/keys/db1a.key

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error on Galera, but a "logical error" at application level. Thank Galera that the error ocurred and it didn't corrupt your topology or break consistency, as it would have happened with standard replication.

This is happening because **you are trying to insert almost simultaneously auto-inc records on both nodes**. Galera has optimistic locking for performance reasons, that is why you get an error.

You can solve this very easily by setting different auto-increment series for both nodes.

This can be easily done by configuring (assuming a 3-node setup):

```
Node 1
======

auto_increment_increment = 3
auto_increment_offset = 0


Node 2
======

auto_increment_increment = 3
auto_increment_offset = 1

Node 3
======

auto_increment_increment = 3
auto_increment_offset = 2
```

Then restart. This will tell MySQL to insert only 1, 4, 7, etc. on node 1; 2, 5, 8,... on node 2 and 3, 6, 9,... on 3. Be careful on not running out of ids!

As I said, this is actually cool to be happening- errors are clearly shown and fixed quickly instead of silent problems. This would have not work very well on standard replication (updates would continue being a problem), but not on Galera- where updates on the same row by default are retried at least once before rollbacking.

Comment: If all writes were aimed at one node and auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset were left at 1, would this situation have been averted ?

Comment: Hey jynus, thanks for the help. But galera is doing that already out of the box with wsrep_auto_increment_control set to ON. I tested that before posting it.

You pointed out a important thing though, running out of ids, I'm sure that will happen. Is there any way to have any kind of locking between auto_increment INSERTS and avoid these holes ?

Comment: @Erico So this happens despite the different increment ids? Because that would mean that its the application's fault for generating its own sequences, or relying on a different innodb_autoinc_lock_mode. Also, locking intra-servers is not possibility in Galera, it has to be solved at application/middleware side by sending problematic writes to the same node.

Comment: @jynus, that's correct. The offset is already happening. I checked the application also and they're all standard single INSERTs without setting the auto-increment value.

If this is not a bug, I'm clearly missing something, probably I'll enable the logs and see what's doing exactly, hopefully I'll find something and I'll post here.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA The thing is the application can't point all writes to one specific node for now unless I drop the whole cluster structure and use a simple 1-1 connection and create a replication for failover only, which I don't think is the best.

Comment: You could use two CNAMEs, 1 that points a specific node as a Master, and the other CNAME shoudl be assigned to a floating load-balanced VIP for SELECTs that can round-robin among the three servers. That may take some additional coding for using two DBVIPs.

Answer (score -1):

Please see the following documentation for why the auto_increment_offset should not be set as described above: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment

```
0 -> 1
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use AWS Loadbalancer for a Percona cluster. At first sight it may seem to work well but the aws loadbalancer does not take into consideration the node state and it will send requests to the node even if the node is out of sync. Make a HA proxy for this.

Comment: I've been using AWS Load Balancer with Percona XtraDB for years, no problems. What determines if load balancer sends requests to each node is the health check used. On my case I use clustercheck which analyses if cluster is in sync or not.